# Is not defining date_default_timezone_set(timezone) ok?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I do not have date_default_timezone_set(timezone); anywhere in my site . I am using time() and date()  at lot of places in my code. Will it create problems because i have not set default timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to set in php.ini:

```
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Or in your PHP script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

If you don't do this, PHP will warn you. But your date() time() functions will continue to work with OS datetime settings.

Comment: If one user in America posted at 10/20/2013 10 am . If a user in japan views that post. what will he see as posted date time? the same 10/20/2013 10 am or something else?

Comment: A user in Japon will see the server's time: the same 10/20/2013 10 am. Only if you take care of the user's timezone using IPs ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on PHP version but starts from PHP 5.4 UTC timezone will used if it didn't set. But it highly recommended set timezone.
http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-09-27-1
Also, php will throw E_WARNING message if timezone isn't valid or empty